# How to let my CPU run in its max frequency at stress test?

Tags: linux, debian, cpu

I have an old Lenovo ThinkStation P500 with a Xeon E5-2670v3 CPU. `inxi` shows that its freq range is 1.2G~3.1G.

```
bruin@debian:/sys/bus$ inxi -C
CPU:       Info: 12-Core model: Intel Xeon E5-2670 v3 bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 30 MiB
           Speed: 2594 MHz min/max: 1200/3100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 2594 2: 2594 3: 2594 4: 2594 5: 2594 6: 2594 7: 2594
           8: 2594 9: 2594 10: 2594 11: 2594 12: 2594 13: 2594 14: 2594 15: 2594 16: 2594 17: 2594 18: 2594 19: 2594 20: 2594
           21: 2594 22: 2594 23: 2594 24: 2594
```

But when I running spec2017 to stress test the CPU, each core is running at about 2.6G (instead of 3.1G as I expected).

Also, as tested, `sudo cpupower frequency-set -f 3.1G` does not help. However, if the freuquency specified on the command line is lower than 2.6G, the command takes effect as reflectec in output of `/proc/cpuinfo`, values above 2.6G seems having no effect.

I am wondering what's the reason for that, and how to let the CPU goes to its maximum frequency under stress test?

btw, I am currently running Debian 11.3.

Comment: Your problem is perhaps that only one core can do turbo.

Comment: I guess you are right. I was running 24 copy intrate tests of spec2017, meaning each core has a copy of work to do. Now if I run just one copy of intrate test, I can see that frequencies of some cores may reach over 3GHz now and then, as OS schedules the 1 copy test among available cores "randomly".

Comment: ... and I watched this video to get more understanding of Intel's "turbo boost" technology: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5KmctjK-x4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your CPU is rated for 2.6GHz as it's "nominal" peak clock speed.

Per [Intel ARK: Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2670](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/64595/intel-xeon-processor-e52670-20m-cache-2-60-ghz-8-00-gts-intel-qpi.html)

> | CPU Specifications |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | Processor Base Frequency | 2.60 GHz |

The 3.3GHz is a "Turbo" speed that is dependent on power and thermal budgets and is not guaranteed to be available all the time. It depends on the task being run and may only be available when only 1 core is in use.

> | CPU Specifications |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | Max Turbo Frequency | 3.30 GHz |

2.6GHz is effectively the "100%" duty CPU speed, not 3.3GHz. As far as I know there is [no way to permanently force the CPU to operate in Turbo Boost](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432261/how-to-force-all-cpu-cores-to-run-at-maximum-turbo-boost-frequency) without actually overclocking it. Turbo Boost simply lets the CPU clock itself higher to increase performance without any input from the OS.

Turbo Boost speeds (i.e. speeds above 2.6GHz) are at the discretion of the hardware and are simply a "you are allowed to boost if you can" on/off switch, they are not actively selected by the Kernel.